# UITableView background color and separator style change not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I tried to change the background and separator style in a UITableView, but nothing happens. In the snippet below, everything besides those changes works.

This tableView is located in a @IBDesignable UIView. Best part is, that everything shows as it should in the interface builder. The colors change, the separators dissapear.

```
func getTableViewToDisplayRecords() -> UITableView {
        let tableView:UITableView  = UITableView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: (self.frame.size.height * 3) / 4)), style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame:CGRectZero)
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        tableView.separatorStyle = .None

        return tableView
    }
```

What could be causing this behavior?

----- EDIT -----

I have managed to do a workaround:

```
UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .None
```

Now everything works fine, although this is not really a solution of the problem. Any new ideas anyone?

Comment: If your TableView has rows in it, you need to change the background color of the rows too

Comment: The rows also have clear background, and there is no problem to set a different color.

Comment: where do you call this method?

Comment: It is called from the Init method

Comment: which color you are getting in output?

Comment: i am getting the standard colors, which are white for background, and gray for separator

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try the code snippet below to change the background colour of UITableview along with no separator between the table cell's.

```
{
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
}
```

Also, you need to change the background color of UITableViewCells

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // change the background color of cell, which is by-default white
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    return cell
}
```

Here is the screenshot with the table background color being red (for demonstration purpose) and no seperator between cell.

[image]

And here is another image with table background being red and single line seperator between cell.

[image]

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but this is exactly what I have been doing, and this does NOT work, which is the topic of this question.

Comment: I have edited my answer with some screen shots. Its working at my side. You can clean the project and delete derive data or may be re-start the xcode. It might work then.

Comment: Cleaning the project and restarting XCode does nothing.

Comment: Here is the link to download the demo project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/250begwboy2usz7/Swift%202.zip?dl=0

Comment: thanks. working for me to set tableView.backgroundColor. I don't understand why this doesn't seem to work in Interface Builder, but at least this solution is available.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a Bug in UITableView.
When your tableView move to superview, sometimes the 'separatorStyle' property will reset to UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine(the default style).
So you must set this property again when you finish frame change. Like this:

```
    [self.view addSubview:_searchContentView];
    _searchContentView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```